# What was the reason behind using quotes in Go's import statements?

Tags: language-design, history, go

The usage of quotes in Go's `import` statement strikes me as unnecessary. Typical Go import statements look like:

```
import "foo/bar"
import other_name "foo/bar"
import (
    "foo/bar"
    x "foo/baz/bar"
)
```

According to [this Quora post](http://qr.ae/RgxQ1P), it's for unusual paths containing weird characters.

As far as I can tell:

- C and C++ `#include` can have weird paths
- Java is rather strict
- You can [work around in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9123517/2072269)

It strikes me as an unusual concession to make - how often does one see `import`/`include`s using paths with spaces or other weird characters? What was the original reason behind requiring quoted paths? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: I'd guess that it's because you can include urls in them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if they're a core golang dev, but Aram Hăvărneanu answered this question [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/13cnbcy3nt/go-nuts-why-use-double-quotes-to-quote-package-name-when-using-import):

> The structure of an import path is not part of the language
>   specification, so it has to be a string [...] to allow flexibility and to avoid locking in
>   some semantics forever.

I agree with you: I think the majority of programmers won't need those non-standard paths and Aram's justification smells of [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Sure, support for some alternative import or "weird paths" might be nice, but it should be optional, without forcing this ugliness upon everyone.

Comment: Aram's prudence seems sensible to me.  Only the golang team knows precisely what their costs are, and maintaining something as part of the language specification does carry a cost.

Comment: Another factor could be that afaik, Go was developed for Google's server needs. Maybe they needed the custom imports, with their distributed architectures and whatnot?